# Finding the constant that results in the volume of the solid

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, solid-of-revolution

Good afternoon, I came across the following problem and I couldn't find a way to solve it

"Given the following pieces of information:

$a>0$

$R=${$(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2|x \geq 0,a \leq y\leq −ln(ax)$}, where $S$ is a solid obtained by the revolution of the area $R$ around the $x$ axis

find the value of $a$, knowing that the volume of $S$ is equal to $4$"

I tried to integrate and apply the method to find the volume of the solids of revolution but I can never get rid of this constant a Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Please use MathJax to render the math Thanks

Comment: Please show your work. What do you mean get rid of the constant? The constant should be in the answer, and then you solve for it by knowing the total volume is $4$. Welcome to MSE, but please don't use tags that are not appropriate.

Comment: P.S. You will need to use a calculator or numerical methods, ultimately, to solve for $a$.